# How to display output in the for loop horizontally?

Tags: powershell, string-formatting

I'm creating a program that display n number of prime number (e.g. The program will display first 6 prime numbers if the user inputted 6). And I want the display 1 row contains 5 numbers. I did googled it around to find the solution but failed to find it.

I have tried using if else statement to do it but not working

```
for ( $i = 3; $i -gt 0; ++$i ) #starting from 3
    {
        $sqrt = [math]::Sqrt($i)    #Optimize memory consumption
        for ( $j = 2; $j -le $sqrt; ++$j )    #Checked if it is divisible by any natural number
        {
            if ( $i % $j -eq 0 )    #if is prime number
            {
                $prime = 1    #set to false
                break    #stop taking into account
            }
        }
        if ( $prime -eq 0 )    #if not prime number
        {
            Write-Host ("$i")   #display prime number

            $count++    #set count to 1
            $turn++    #set turn to 1
        }
        $prime = 0    #is prime number
        if ( $count -eq $value )    #if until nth prime number
        {
            break    #stop taking into account
        }
        if ( $turn -eq 5 )
        {
           Write-Output(" ")
           $turn = 0
        }
    }
```

I'm expecting the result is like:
3
5
7
11
13

17
19
23
29
31

But it gave me the output like this:
3
5
7
11
13

17
19
23
29
31

Any suggestions / advice is welcomed. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some general pointers:

- **Avoid mixing `Write-Host` and `Write-Output`** calls for constructing your output - these cmdlets serve very different purposes.

  - [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) - whose explicit use is rarely necessary - outputs *data*, for later *programmatic processing*.

    - Any command or expression's output that is not captured in a variable, sent to another command via the pipeline, or redirected to a file is *implicitly* output, so that `Write-Output $i` can simply be written as `$i`.
  - [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) writes to the *host* (typically, the console) and provides *feedback to the user* in the form of status information or to aid in soliciting input - it writes to an [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection) that is *separate* from the *data* (success output) stream, and as such you shouldn't use it to output *data*, because such output can (without extra effort) neither be captured in a variable nor sent to another command.
- **Avoid pseudo method syntax such as `Write-Output(" ")`** when you call PowerShell commands (cmdlets / functions / scripts):

  - In PowerShell, commands are invoked *like shell commands* - `Write-Output arg1 arg2` - *not* like C# methods - `Write-Output(arg1, arg2)`; see [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing).
    To prevent accidental use of method syntax, use [`Set-StrictMode -Version 2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) or higher, but note its other effects.

---

If you want to **output an *array* of objects on the same line, simply *stringify* it via an [*expandable string*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) (interpolating string), `"..."`**, which creates a space-separated<sup>[1]</sup> list of its (stringified) elements:

```
function get-Primes {
  param($n)
  1..$n # simulate output: simply return array 1, 2, 3, ...
}

# Get an array of numbers
$primes = get-Primes 5

# Output the array as a space-separated list, via an expandable string:
"$primes"
```

The above yields:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

---

<sup>[1] The space char. is the default separator, but the `$OFS` preference variable can be used to specify a different char.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Question solved.
By using -NoNewLine command and put some effort on "decorating" the output.

Expected result achieved.

Thank you so much.

Comment: you can also add them to a collection and then use `$Collection -join ' '` to make a neat, space-delimited string ... and then write that to the screen. [*grin*]